# Testing controllers in Rails 3 with Devise and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I am trying to test my controller's `create` action. I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, and have used the before_filter method to limit access to the `create` action to logged-in users. Here is the relevant part of my controller.

```
class RawDataSetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index, :download]

  def create
    @raw_data_set = current_user.raw_data_sets.build(params[:raw_data_set])
    if @raw_data_set.save
      redirect_to @raw_data_set
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

In my test case I want to make sure that a logged-in user can create a RawDataSet. I think that I have mocked up an authenticated user according to the instructions on [this](http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=349) blog post.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe RawDataSetsController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  def mock_users(stubs={})
    @user ||= mock_model(User, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  def log_in_test_user
    attr = { :username => "Foobar", :email => "doineedit@foobar.com" }
    #mock up an authentication in warden as per http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=349
    request.env['warden'] = mock(Warden, :authenticate => mock_users(attr),
                                         :authenticate! => mock_users(attr),
                                         :authenticate? => mock_users(attr))
  end

  before do
    @rds = Factory(:raw_data_set)
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do

    before do
      @attr = { 
        :organism_name => "Beef Jerky",
        :mass_spec_type => "My Stomach",
      }
    end

    describe "logged in user" do
      it "should create a raw_data_set when the user is logged in" do
        log_in_test_user
        lambda do
          post :create, :raw_data_set => @attr
        end.should change(RawDataSet, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running this test case causes the following error:

```
1) RawDataSetsController POST 'create' logged in user should create a raw_data_set when the user is logged in
 Failure/Error: post :create, :raw_data_set => @attr
 undefined method `user_url' for #<RawDataSetsController:0x0000010175af88>
 # ./app/controllers/raw_data_sets_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

I am baffled by this error. Upon more inspection, @raw_data_set is not an instance of the RawDataSet model class, but a user? This is what it looks like when I `p @raw_data_set`

```
#<User:0x807a06a4 @name="User_1002">
```

What the devil is going on? What am I doing wrong? How can I test the create action on my controller with a an authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** *(totally wrong first attempt removed)*

Calling `as_null_object` essentially tells the mock to accept all messages that aren't stubbed and just return self. So when you call

`current_user.raw_data_sets.build(params[:raw_data_set])`

which would normally return a new `RawDataSet` associated to `current_user`, instead you get `current_user` again.

So when you try to call redirect, passing in `@raw_data_set`, you're passing it the mock instead of a `RawDataSet` instance, thus the errant call to `user_url`.

I think the way to handle this is just use a real User (or a Factory) and stub out the Devise methods on it. So your `mock_users` becomes (for instance):

```
  def mock_users(stubs={})
    @user = User.create(stubs)
  end
```

Now `current_user` will actually do the build and save through the association.

Purists will tell you to mock and stub out everything until you're blue in the face. Screw that -- you've got better things to do. :)

The other way to approach this is to test that the build message is received without checking whether the save succeeded. Presumably your model tests will verify that saving through the association works -- why test again in the controller?

Comment: The problem is that this line from the controller: @raw_data_set = current_user.raw_data_sets.build(params[:raw_data_set]) is returning an instance of the User class in my test, which is not at all what I want it to do. It should be an instance of the RawDataSet class, and redirect to RawDataSets#show.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still getting the hang of RSpec, so this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something specific for example change the behavior of sign-in, you can inherit from devise controllers and overwrite them.
you can follow the instruction from here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise the configuring controllers.